# What is the difference between these two functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen some people define functions like I do:

```
function stuff(){ /*code here*/ }
```

And I've seen others do this:

```
(function stuff(){ /*code here*/ })();
```

What's the difference in having the parenthesis outline the function? Does it actually do anything?

*Note: This may be a duplicate, but I didn't find the answer online since I didn't phrase it very well.*

Comment: Are you sure your didn't mean (function stuff () {
 /*code here*/
})();

Comment: This was the beginning of my answer: The first one is a function **declaration**. Function declarations create a new binding in the current scope, so you can reference the function by its name. The second one is a function **expression**. Inside the "grouping operator" (`(...)`) can only be expressions, hence the function definition is interpreted as function expression. The name of the function doesn't create a binding outside the function itself. The function can only be accessed by its name inside itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're thinking of is an immediately-invoked function expression and can be used to produce lexical scoping (i.e. private variables,etc.). Check out the wiki article [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Here's an example from the wiki:

```
var counter = (function(){
 var i = 0;

 return {
   get: function(){
     return i;
   },
   set: function( val ){
     i = val;
   },
   increment: function() {
     return ++i;
   }
 };
})();
```

In this case, `i` is not available on the outside.

Comment: Do you see any function call here ?

Comment: I don't, but I figured OP didn't know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably seen others do this:

```
(function stuff(){ /*code here*/ })();
```

That line will define a function and immediately execute it.